# Searching for an image that already exist in plist file (xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, plist, uisearchbar

I am a new iphone developer, I am currently working on a project. **Firstly I have a plist file that contain images.These images have their own id. For ex. image1's id is '100', image2's id is '101'. I also have a search bar in my app. When I entered a number(id) to the search bar, I want to get image from plist file,and show it in UIImageView.For ex. I entered '100' to my search bar. The image that its id is '100' will shown in UIImageView. ** Actually I have no idea about how to do this with xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way to get those images from plist. after getting in array you can use NSPredicate or search from an array to get your desired result.

```
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EventAddress" ofType:@"plist"]; 
  NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
  NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary  allValues];
```

Comment: Ok I got the images from plist to array.I used this code:  self.resimler =[[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rsm" ofType:@"plist"]] retain];      After this, how can I search this array with searchbar and How can I show the searching result

Comment: There is delegate method in searchbar that can help you like:
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText

Then you can use predicate to filter data

NSPredicate * predicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(title CONTAINS[cd] %@), searchText];
self.displayedData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.resimler filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];